# Is there a lens hood, step up filter ring combination in the market?

Tags: lens, filters, adapter, lens-hood

I have a 58mm filter threaded lens and I want to use my 77mm filters on it. I thought maybe I could buy a hood that is double threaded for different sizes. This would probably look less awkward than having a direct 58-77mm step up filter adapter on it. Does such a product exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it exists as the shape of a lens hood is determined by the angle of view of the lens, you would need a different step-up hood combo for every different filter diameter *and* every different focal length.

Also screwing on a filter inside the hood would be fiddly. What you want is a lens hood that attaches to a 77mm filter thread, but then I fear it would be fragile and prone to damaging the threads due to the bulk of the hood and the risk of knocking it.